# Angular Abstract Class TypeError

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am getting an odd Type Error when I start using Abstract Classes in Angular 16.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.httpService.get is not a function

Maybe my understanding around the useage of Abstract Classes is wrong?
It works when I remove the Abstract class and just call the http.service directly.

**Models/HttpResponse.ts**

```
export class HttpResponse {
  status: string | undefined;
  data: any;
  success: string | undefined;
  message: string | undefined;
}
```

**Services/http.abstract_service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export abstract class AbstractHttpService {
    public abstract get(url: string): Observable<any>;
    
}
```

**Services/http.service.ts**

```
import { AbstractHttpService } from './http.abstract_service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpResponse } from '@models/http_response';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpService implements AbstractHttpService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }


    // GET Request
    get(url: string): Observable<any> {


        return this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                let responseBody = res?.body;
                let result: HttpResponse;
                if(res){

                    result = { 
                        status: res.status, 
                        data: responseBody.data,
                        success: responseBody.success, 
                        message: responseBody.message
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log(`Error! HttpStatus: ${res.status}`);
                }

                return result;
            }));
    }
```

**Services/data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractHttpService } from './http.abstract_service';
import { HttpResponse } from '@models/http_response';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
    constructor( private httpService: AbstractHttpService ){ }

    getMyData(): Observable<HttpResponse> {

        const url = `${MyApiUrl}/Data`;

        // This is the problem? When I make it of type HttpService and avoid the abstract class it works.
        const response = this.httpService.get(url);

        return response;
        
    }
```

**Pages/my/my.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Result } from '@models/result';
import { DataService } from '@services/data.service'
import { HttpResponse } from '@models/http_response';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})


export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource: Result[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }


   onGetMyData() {
    this.dataService.getMyData().subscribe((response: HttpResponse) => {

      console.log(`Status: ${response.status} Success: ${response.success} Data:`, response.data.results);

      response.data.results.forEach((val: any) => {
        this.dataSource.push(Object.assign({}, val))
      });

    });
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.onGetMyData();
  }


}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using extends instend of implement

```
export class HttpService extends AbstractHttpService
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work. It wanted a super(); call in the constructor as well but then reported the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably mixing classes: you're using abstract class, instead of a class which implements it, hence the error.

In `Services/data.service.ts`, import the http service class - `Services/http.service.ts`, not abstract class - `Services/http.abstract_service.ts`:

Try this:

in Services/data.service.ts,

instead of:

```
import { AbstractHttpService } from './http.abstract_service';

constructor( private httpService: AbstractHttpService ){ }
```

use

```
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

constructor( private httpService: HttpService ){ }
```

**edit**

if you're trying to create a service with different implementations of abstract class, you can use abstract class as a token in [`providers`](https://angular.io/guide/providers), and define the service which implements it:

```
providers: [ {provide:AbstractHttpService, useClass: HttpService } ]
```

For example, later you can switch to a different implementation:

```
providers: [ {provide:AbstractHttpService, useClass: SomeDifferentHttpService } ]
```

Comment: Yes, as I said when I do this it works. What's the abstract class for then if I don't use it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I don't need to use abstract classes then? Why would I use them?

Comment: ah, right. see my edit, you just add the service in the providers, and it should work. abstract classes serve as interfaces for classes, so you can use it as a type checker, but you can also use abstract class as a token for injecting different implementations. Also, as abstract class doesn't implement method, you can use implements instead of extends